# sbt-assembly not including dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to build a fat jar to send to spark-submit using sbt assembly. However, I cannot seem to get the build process right.

My current build.sbt is as follows

```
name := "MyAppName"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"


libraryDependencies  ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.0" % "provided",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.12",
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % "0.12"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)
```

Running sbt-sssembly produces a jar. However, after submitting the jar to spark-submit 
`spark-submit MyAppName-assembly-1.0.jar` (there's already a main class specified so I'm assuming its ok I don't specify a class), the following exception gets thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.DenseVector.noOffsetOrStride()Z
at breeze.linalg.DenseVector$canDotD$.apply(DenseVector.scala:629)
at breeze.linalg.DenseVector$canDotD$.apply(DenseVector.scala:626)
at breeze.linalg.ImmutableNumericOps$class.dot(NumericOps.scala:98)
at breeze.linalg.DenseVector.dot(DenseVector.scala:50)
at RunMe$.cosSimilarity(RunMe.scala:103)
at RunMe$$anonfun$4.apply(RunMe.scala:35)
at RunMe$$anonfun$4.apply(RunMe.scala:33)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:30)
at org.spark-project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:658)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1374)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm relatively new to the world of scala and sbt, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea See if the advice there works for u

Comment: the error isn't exactly the same, my dependency isn't being included in my JAR but there's no issue with the JAR being submitted to spark itself.

Comment: When you run `assemblyPackageDependency` you should get a jar named something like `MyAppName-assembly-1.0-deps.jar`. That will contain your deps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the issue is that breeze is already included in spark. The issue was that spark contained a newer Breeze version with methods that my version didn't have.

My reference: [Apache Spark - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.DenseVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855776/apache-spark-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-breeze-linalg-densevector)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I ended up saving the jar under lib directory then in assembly.sbt add :

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/my.jar")
```