# Tell Spark to use the version of Breeze I want

Tags: apache-spark, scala-breeze

I use [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) for an algorithm that I wish to deploy in a cluster using Spark. When running my algorithm on Spark, I get the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.sum$.helper_Double()Lbreeze/linalg/VectorizedReduceUFunc$VectorizeHelper;`.

`sum()` works perfectly when I use my algorithm locally, questions concerning this error [have already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855776/apache-spark-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-breeze-linalg-densevector) but the answer does not satisfy me: I do need to use Breeze 0.12, not the version that Spark use. How to do so? I am using SBT and assembly to build the fat JAR that Spark uses.